# Is there a way to tell if an email address corresponds to a Google account?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api

I am working on a Google Sheets add-on that calls [`Permissions: insert`](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v2/reference/permissions/insert) as described in [a Stack Overflow answer](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v2/reference/permissions/insert):

```
function addUserPermission(fileId, email, notify) {
  Drive.Permissions.insert({
    'value': email,
    'type': 'user',
    'role': 'reader',
    'withLink': false
  },
    fileId,
    {
      'sendNotificationEmails': notify
    });
}
```

The `notify` flag is `true` if the user should receive an email notification of the added permission, `false` if they should not.

If the `email` value is associated with a Google account (such as `foo@gmail.com`), this works whether `notify` is `true` or `false`. If the `email` value is not associated with a Google account, an exception is thrown if `notify` is `false`:

> ScriptError: GoogleJsonResponseException: API call to drive.permissions.insert
> failed with error: Bad Request. User message: "You are trying to invite
> fakeaddress@nowhere.com. Since there is no Google account associated with this email address,
> you must check the "Notify people" box to invite this recipient."

Is there any way to tell *before* calling `Drive.permissions.insert` that the email address is not associated with a Google account?

Comment: Not that I know of. But, isn't the failure a flag on it's own?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### This is only possible for Admin Users

If you are an admin for your Google Workspace, you may use `AdminDirectory.Users.get("userEmail")` to check whether the google account (under your google workspace) exists or not. You may use the following script as the base for your code:

```
function getUser(userEmail) {
  try {
    const user = AdminDirectory.Users.get(userEmail);
    Logger.log("Email exists");
  } catch (err) {
    Logger.log('Email does not exist. Error: %s', err.message);
  }
}
```

**NOTE:** This script only works if:

1. You are an administrator in your Google Workspace.
2. The google account is registered under your Google Workspace.
3. AdminDirectory service is added to the Apps Script project.

### Reference

For further details, you may read the following:

1. [Admin SDK Directory Service/Get User](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/advanced/admin-sdk-directory#get_user)

Comment: Thank you! I did not expect an authoritative answer.